# eclipse juno showing error editor does not contain main file, i think the editor has some error not the code

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class JavaSourceViewer{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String java.io.BufferedReader.readLine() throws IOException

    System.out.print("Enter url of local for viewing html source code: ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String url = br.readLine();

    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        int code = uc.getResponseCode();
        String response = uc.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println("HTTP/1.x " + code + " " + response);

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int c;
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("D://web-content.txt");
        while ((c = r.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)c);
            fout.write(c);
        }
        fout.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.err.println(url + " is not a valid URL.");
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Input/Output Error: " + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know what is wrong with this, but the code is not running just showing the error.

Comment: "answer soon"... ???? we aren't your maid

Comment: And what error is shown?

Answer (score 2):

It *is* the code. Looks like you've got a copy/paste error. Method declarations are not permitted within the body of other methods. Remove this partial method declaration from the `main` method

```
String java.io.BufferedReader.readLine() throws IOException
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes restarting the eclipse solves it. Also make sure the jdk path is accurate and try to configure it again and finally clean the project using the eclipse tool

Comment: ok it is working now but the program has to print the html code of a particular website when enetered, but it is showing invalid url even when i have enetred google.com......what should i do?

Comment: ohh god i am a big fool thank-you so mush for this suggestion....its working now and it is showing the html code and also saving the html code in a text file.